# IS there any equivalent data structure available in C# for BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Im using PLinq, I have to add collection of items for each PLINQ to Shared Collection , Currently im using BlockingCollection> is there any other Data structure available in C# which does similar functionality. I need to have this collection to hold distinct values for given key.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)? It would be nice if you explained your requirements better. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "hold distinct values for given key"? Does that mean that you want to be able to add several items that have the same key, and to have each of those items treated as a distinct entity?

Comment: yes matthew, I want have distinct KEY VALUE to be stored . I may have multiple Keys with same names but there values might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, by creating List> with IComparer.

Here is Comparer
public class KeyValueComparer : IEqualityComparer>
    {
        public bool Equals(KeyValuePair x, KeyValuePair y)
        {
            return (x.Key == y.Key && x.Value == y.Value);
        }

```
    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, string> referenceObj)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(referenceObj, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = referenceObj.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)) ? 0 : referenceObj.Value.GetHashCode();

        return hashProductName;
    }
}
```

I Try Call on collection
 var collection= CollectionWithKVPair.Distinct(new KeyValueComparer());

This will solve problem where list with multiple same keys but different values.